# Create a legend for user-defined marker_colors in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I´ve set manually colors for some bars of a bar plot (one which corresponds to the max value and another one - to the value I´d like to draw attention to).

Here´s a sample of the df

```
  ranking = df['rank_1', 'rank_2', 'rank_3', 'rank_4', 'rank_5', 'rank_6'].mean()
    >>> ranking

   rank_1   3.267
   rank_2   2.911
   rank_3   2.654
   rank_4   3.729
   rank_5   4.485
   rank_6   3.953
```

Here´s how I plot it.

```
fig = px.bar(ranking, x=ranking.values, y=ranking.index, orientation='h', 
         labels={'x': 'average rank', 'y': 'movie'})

colors=[] 
for val in ranking.values:
    colors.append('rgb(252, 128, 14)' if val ==  ranking.values.max() else 'rgb(137, 137, 137)')
colors[1] = 'rgb(95, 158, 209)'

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='<i>Average rank:</i> %{x:.2f}', marker_color=colors)
```

How can I create a legend for colors used in the plot?

Comment: What does the DataFrame `ranking` look like? Can you provide a sample of it?

Comment: Yes, sure. I´ve added it to the question

Comment: Often in plotly one adds a faux dataseries for a legend. This is true for scatter blob sizes for example. However this is not the case really here. For a scatterplot where the colour is categorical, one add a grouping column and then use the `color` argument. For a bar chart a stacked bar would work.